# Angular | How do i show an object inside the form of another component

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a picture of the app so you can understand what im talking about: [image: snap]

So i'm trying to create a webapp in Angular where you can add appointments and display the array of appointments. Im doing this for learning reasons only

As you can see in the image, you can add the appointments on the left and see the list on the right.

Now what i want to do is pass the appointment object to the form when you hit the enter button in the list but i dont know how to do that...

Ive already tried to inject the form component (left) into the listcomponent (right) so i can pass it directly on the (click) event of the button and that kinda worked, i could successfully log the appointment but it just didnt show up in the form.

Im already sorry for the amount of code im gonna put here but im a beginner so dont go too hard on me

This is the form-component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-form',
  templateUrl: './appointment-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-form.component.css']
})
export class AppointmentFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      companyName: '',
      notes: '',
      date: '',
      time: ''
    })
  }

  onAddAppointment() {
    this.appointmentService.addAppointment(this.form.value);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      companyName: '',
      notes: '',
      date: '',
      time: ''
    })
  }

  onEditAppointment(i) {
    this.form = this.fb.group(this.appointmentService.editAppointment(i));
    this.form.controls['companyName'].setValue(this.appointmentService.editAppointment(i).companyName);
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

And here is its html file:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onAddAppointment()">
    <h4 class="title">Add a new Appointment</h4>
    <hr>

    <h5 class="title">Company Name</h5>
    <input class="textinput" formControlName="companyName" required>

    <div class="sectionlarge">
        <h5 class="title">Day of Arrival</h5>
        <input class="textinput" placeholder="Month Day, Year" formControlName="date" required [(ngModel)]="form.date">
    </div>

    <div class="sectionsmall">
        <h5 class="title">Time</h5>
        <input class="textinput" placeholder="00:00" maxlength="5" formControlName="time" required>
    </div>

    <h5 class="title">Additional Notes</h5>
    <textarea class="textinput" rows="4" formControlName="notes" required></textarea>
    <hr>

    <button class="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And heres my list-component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-list',
  templateUrl: './appointment-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-list.component.css']
})
export class AppointmentListComponent implements OnInit {
  appointments: Appointment[] = [];
  @Output() passData: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    private formcomponent: AppointmentFormComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appointments = this.appointmentService.getAppointments();
  }

  onEdit(i) {
    this.formcomponent.onEditAppointment(i);
    console.log("list component check");
  }

  onClick(i) {
    this.passData.emit(i);
  }
}
```

Of course with its corrisponding html:

```html
<h4 class="title">List of Appointments</h4>
<hr>

<div *ngFor="let appointment of appointments ; index as i">
    <h5 class="title">{{ appointment.companyName }}<button class="edit" (click)="onEdit(i)">Edit</button></h5>
    <div class="info">
        <section>Time of arrival: <section class="float">{{ appointment.date }} | {{ appointment.time }}</section>
        </section>
        <section>{{ appointment.notes }}</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also the service editAppointment function:

```js
editAppointment(i) {
    return this.appointments[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your AppointmentFormComponent add an Input to get data, also patch your form to set that data to your form something like below

```
export class AppointmentFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() appointment: Appointment;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private appointmentService: AppointmentService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      companyName: '',
      notes: '',
      date: '',
      time: ''
    });

    this.patchForm();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: Record<keyof AppointmentFormComponent, SimpleChange>) {
    if (changes.appointment && changes.appointment.currentValue) {
       this.pacthForm();
    }
  }

  patchForm() {
    if (this.form && this.appointment) {
        this.form.patchValue(this.appointment);
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help, i didnt even know about ngOnChanges.
But i dont get the @ Input to work, could you explain to me what i need to add in the other files? Is the @ Input even possible, since the components are siblings?

Comment: Also the console logs an error "this.form is undefined" in the patchForm function, but shouldnt it be defined from the ngOninit?

Comment: for @Input to work, you need to add `[appointment]="selectedAppointment"` in the appointment form html tag, also you need to have something like selectedAppointment and when user clicks on any appointment the assign it, also for patchForm I already added some if, so it should be working, btw for being able to help you better please create stackblitz

Comment: The reason it didnt work properly was bc i injected the one component into its sibling to transfer the data. It works now, now im passing the data to the components parent through output and input. Also thanks for the tip with stackblitz, ill make sure to add a stackblitz the next time i have a question. Thanks for your help

Comment: great, just as a general note if you assign the @input manually by code (not through attributes) the `ngOnChanges` doesn't fire, then you need to change it `get`,`set` to be able to handle changes